# VB.NET Connect to MS Access with linked SQL Server tables

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, windows-services, ms-access-2003

I'm trying to create a Windows Service that connects to a development database (MS Access 2003 *.mdb), but I'm running into connection errors. The Access DB contains linked tables to the SQL Server DB and I have the credentials to create new linked tables (idk if this is enough to connect to the SQL Server DB). I've made several other WinForm applications that successfully connect via OleDb connection and they continue to work.

Now, I've tried the [OleDb connection](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?632144-VB-Net-connection-to-MS-Acces-linked-table) in the Windows Service to no avail and I've tried [multiple drivers](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/310985) with the OdBc connection. I've tried changing the `ServiceInstaller` account type between `User` and `LocalSystem` and even the `Target CPU` for poops and giggles (been burned before on that one). Ultimately, I think the scope of a Windows Service screws with any OdBc connections, which I think will require a direct connection to the SQL Server DB.

Is there a method that I may have missed that would allow me to continue using the MS Access database and subsequently the OleDb connection I have in my existing applications?

Comment: Loose the MS Access, have your Windows Service directly connect to the SQL server.

Comment: If you connect directly you will have a lot of advantages like better performance, more security and a native support for your querys etc etc

Comment: That's what I was afraid of lol. Management is a bit touchy on access to the database because we're technically not even supposed to access it directly as it's part of our ERP system. Understandably, they don't want stuff accidentally deleted or changed. I found an unrelated solution by using a scheduled task on MS Access.